# How do I initialize a String variable? Code has no errors but does not compile due to uninitialized variable, name

Tags: java, string

I wrote this code but I think I did something wrong because it's not printing out like it's supposed to. The user puts in their name and it's supposed to spit out a description for each letter of their name. Everything about the code is perfect except that it is not recognizing the variable letter.  How do I initialize it in order for it to work?

This is due today. Can someone take a look at it and tell me what I'm missing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This program asks for a mane and will print out
 * an acrostic name poem.
 *
 * @author ()
 * @version (October 24th, 2017)
 */
public class AcrosticName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;        //a string of characters
        String letter = "";
        int length;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Print a program header
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Arcostic Poem Maker");
        System.out.println();

        //Have user enter their name
        System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        length = name.length();

        //for a loop to go through the name
        //and find letters used in name
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (letter.equals("A") || letter.equals("a")) {
                System.out.println(" A is for Academic, you are smart");
            } else if (letter.equals("B") || letter.equals("b")) {
                System.out.println(" B is for Benevolent, you are nice");
            } else if (letter.equals("C") || letter.equals("c")) {
                System.out.println("C is for Cosmopolitan, well-versed in cultures");
            } else if (letter.equals("D") || letter.equals("d")) {
                System.out.println("D is for Decent, a heart of gold");
            } else if (letter.equals("E") || letter.equals("e")) {
                System.out.println("E is for Enigmatic, you have an alluring pull");
            } else if (letter.equals("F") || letter.equals("f")) {
                System.out.println("F is for Fine, a jolly good fellow");
            } else if (letter.equals("G") || letter.equals("g")) {
                System.out.println("G is for Gentle, a kind soul ");
            } else if (letter.equals("H") || letter.equals("h")) {
                System.out.println(" H is for Hip, cooler than everyone else");
            } else if (letter.equals("I") || letter.equals("i")) {
                System.out.println("I is for Independent, never swayed by others");
            } else if (letter.equals("J") || letter.equals("j")) {
                System.out.println("J is for Joyful, radiating bliss");
            } else if (letter.equals("K") || letter.equals("k")) {
                System.out.println("K is for Kindred, you feel like family");
            } else if (letter.equals("L") || letter.equals("l")) {
                System.out.println("L is for Light-hearted, you have an easy laughter");
            } else if (letter.equals("M") || letter.equals("m")) {
                System.out.println("M is for Meticulous, careful with details");
            } else if (letter.equals("N") || letter.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("N is for Nutty, full of wackiness");
            } else if (letter.equals("O") || letter.equals("o")) {
                System.out.println("O is for Oasis, full of zen");
            } else if (letter.equals("P") || letter.equals("p")) {
                System.out.println("P is for Popular, liked by all");
            } else if (letter.equals("Q") || letter.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("Q is for Quintessential, the epitome of awesomeness");
            } else if (letter.equals("R") || letter.equals("r")) {
                System.out.println("R is for Ravishing, an entrancing beauty");
            } else if (letter.equals("S") || letter.equals("s")) {
                System.out.println("S is for Sharp, always observant");
            } else if (letter.equals("T") || letter.equals("t")) {
                System.out.println("T is for Tolerant, endless patience");
            } else if (letter.equals("U") || letter.equals("u")) {
                System.out.println("U is for Unassuming, ever humble");
            } else if (letter.equals("V") || letter.equals("v")) {
                System.out.println("V is for Virtuous, living in righteousness");
            } else if (letter.equals("W") || letter.equals("w")) {
                System.out.println("W is for Wacky, a unique personality");
            } else if (letter.equals("X") || letter.equals("x")) {
                System.out.println("X is for X-ray, you're a visionary");
            } else if (letter.equals("Y") || letter.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("Y is for Youth, eternally young at heart");
            } else if (letter.equals("Z") || letter.equals("z")) {
                System.out.println("Z is for Zippy, living at breakneck speed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Not printing how it is supposed to" Give more details. What was the input, the output, and the expected output

Comment: So when it is compiled and run, it asks to put a name, for example, Sam.  Its supposed to out put:

Comment: S is for sassy
A is for anxious
M is for meticulous

Comment: All of it would be one under the other on separate lines.
the example i put isnt exactly what on the code but more or less

Comment: Learn about debugging. That would've helped you find the problem very quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the assignation of `letter` at the start of the `for` loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    letter = Character.toString(name.charAt(i));
    //...
```

Comment: its not working.  an error is popping up

Comment: it says an array is required and the instructions say i cant use arrays

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote the answer as C#. I just modified it for Java.

Comment: Hey it works!  Is there any other alternative to this as well? Its for a class and the rubric says we cant use arrays or char.

Comment: It says " You MUST use a String variable for name - do not use char variables or arrays for this program."

Comment: You could've written the string as an array and iterate through the array. `name.charAt(index)` returns an `char`, so storing the letter as a `char` and manipulate you would've remove the conversion from `char` to `string`.

Comment: Try indexOf() perhaps

Comment: I'm new to programming so im not sure what you refer to Eienne... could you code it out to see what u mean?

Comment: Here's a [live demo](http://tpcg.io/3ValXq) of what I refering to.